# Does anyone know this determinant?

Tags: reference-request, determinants

The following determinant arises in a combinatorial enumeration problem. I wonder if anyone has seen it before in any context or knows how to evaluate it. I tried computing it for small $n$ but didn't notice anything interesting.
The values $r_1,r_2,\ldots$ are unspecified real numbers.

$A_n=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$, where
$$a_{ij}=\cases{(r_i+r_j)(1-r_i-r_j)& \text{ if } i\ne j\\[1ex] 
  \sum_{k:k\ne i} a_{ik}& \text{ if }i=j.}$$

For example:
$$A_3 = \left[\matrix{{(r_1{+}r_2)(1{-}r_1{-}r_2)}\atop{ + (r_1{+}r_3)(1{-}r_1{-}r_3)} &
        (r_1{+}r_2)(1{-}r_1{-}r_2) & (r_1{+}r_3)(1{-}r_1{-}r_3) \\[1ex]
 (r_1{+}r_2)(1{-}r_1{-}r_2) &
  {(r_1{+}r_2)(1{-}r_1{-}r_2)}\atop{+(r_2{+}r_3)(1{-}r_2{-}r_3)} & (r_2{+}r_3)(1{-}r_2{-}r_3) \\[1ex]
 (r_1{+}r_3)(1{-}r_1{-}r_3) & (r_2{+}r_3)(1{-}r_2{-}r_3) &
 {(r_1{+}r_3)(1{-}r_1{-}r_3)}\atop{+(r_2{+}r_3)(1{-}r_2{-}r_3)}
}\right].$$

Comment: So you have a complete graph with edges weighted in Hankel matrix-like fashion, and then you take the "unsigned Laplacian" matrix of this (weighted) graph. Hmm...